# Update and import issues with Google Play Service Library

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I have recently updated my google-play-services_library from the SDK manager. I have been using the this library for my maps project and from the manifest file, I noticed that its version

> android:versionName="3.0.27 (601249-10)" >

Now for my Google Cloud Messaging project, I needed to update this library above 3.1. So I updated it from the SDK manager.
But now I can't import the latest library into my workspace. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Part of the reason I believe is because I already have the previous version in my package explorer. So I am not sure how to tackle this issue because I have already used the previous package in different projects that are yet to be finished.
My workspace is in my F drive and my SDK updates get installed in my E drive.
So how should I solve this issue?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is your old google library already exists in your workspace ?

Comment: yes its inside my workspace.

Comment: If its inside your workspace then just shift it somewhere else and then try to import. And now if you import it Do it like `File>Project...>Select Android folder>AndroidProjectFromExistingCode>and browse your project`.

Comment: @GrIsHu I did as said, and now I encounter another problem. Have a look [here](http://s21.postimg.org/da7ouruiv/error.png)

Comment: Its showing error because it doesn't get the `google-play-services_lib.jar` at the specified path.

Comment: Well I did it because the answer below said me to do so, while shift it to somewhere else seems to mean the same to me. How to rectify it?

Comment: As i guess you have deleted the old `google-play-services` project from your workspace. Just delete that reference from your project and add the reference of new `google-play-service_lib` in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Copy that google play service libary in F drive and import that library in workspace. Then delete that libary which is already existing in your workspace. Import this google play service lib(now in F drive) in your workspace.

Comment: shall I check on Copy projects into workspace while importing?

Answer (score 0):

If old `google-play-service` library is inside your workspace then just shift it somewhere else and then try to import. And now if you import it Do it like `File>Project...>Select Android folder>AndroidProjectFromExistingCode>and browse your project`. And your library project will be imported into your workspace.

Comment: Did you mean that I have to keep both the old and new versions in my workspace? I can't import both of them in here. My problem still persists and the error that I have shown before [this](http://s21.postimg.org/da7ouruiv/error.png) still persists. I can't separately delete the missing dependency. If I delete the entire Dependency folder, android regenerates it, but the missing one is still shown as before.

Comment: I am saying that you either remove the old version from your workspace  or just rename the old version in your workspace. and then try to import the new version in workspace.

Comment: The issue about dependency: to resolve it as i said you will have to delete the dependency from your project and again you will have to try to add the libraries with the reference of new version google-play-services library. OK ?

Comment: Its not working this way. I have searched other stackoverflow questions on the same issue, different workouts worked for some of them. The actual thing is, google-play-services_lib.jar is missing for most of the downloads on revision 12.